# Problem with cipher crypting uppercase letter c#

Tags: c#, encryption, caesar-cipher

having problem with crypting the uppercase letters with basic Cipher cryption code in c#, they just translate to symbols
Thanks in advance, I wrote the code below
(Ps, labels and textboxes are in swedish but hope i can get help anyway)

The code:

```
private void btnkryptera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string vanlig = tbxnormaltext.Text;
    int bytanummer = int.Parse(tbxkryptera.Text);

    tbxkryperadtext.Text = görKryptering(vanlig, bytanummer);
}

private static string görKryptering(string ord, int nummer)
{
    char[] längd = ord.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < längd.Length; i++)
    {
        //Separate and change letters
        char bokstav = längd[i];

        //Change letters based on which shift
        bokstav = (char)(bokstav + nummer);

        //Delete 26 on 'overflow'
        //Adds 26 on 'overflow'
        if (bokstav > 'z')
        {
            bokstav = (char)(bokstav - 26);
        }
        else if (bokstav < 'a')
        {
            bokstav = (char)(bokstav + 26);
        }

        //Then save
        längd[i] = bokstav;

    }
    return new string(längd);
}
```

Comment: What are the requirements?  The uppercase letters are < 'a' so you are adding 26.  Try changing < 'a' to < 'A'

Comment: Most commonly Caesar encryptions are uppercase only. So convert your text to uppercase first and then figure it out. Also, the Swedish alphabet may contain more characters? Or do you just have a..z? Accents are usually left out but text may lose meaning after that.

Comment: The requirement is that it need to handle both upper and lower cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lowercase letters are numbered from 'a' == 97 to 'z' == 122. Uppercase are 'A' == 65 to 'Z' == 90.

Thus, your `bokstav < 'a'` will process your uppercase letters and do so incorrectly.

Either put specific coding for uppercase, or use `ToLower()` to convert your plaintext to lowercase.

Comment: Thanks, the program needs to handle both uppcase and lowercase letter. Also having problem with converting space, i the encrypted text it is displayed as an "=", how do i solve this?

Comment: Standard Caesar cipher ignores punctuation and spaces, simply copying them unchanged.

Comment: If you're happy, please select this as the correct answer.

Comment: did not quite solve it with upper case letters, will wait a few hours to see if any other answers come up, otherwise i select this one

Comment: What's the ongoing problem?

Comment: Can’t combine so im able to both crypt upper and lowercase letters

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < längd.Length; i++)
    {
        //Separate and change letters
        char bokstav = längd[i];

        //Change letters based on which shift
        bokstav = (char)(bokstav + nummer);

        //Delete 26 on 'overflow'
        //Adds 26 on 'overflow'
        if (bokstav > 'z')
        {
            bokstav = (char)(bokstav - 26);
        }
        else if (bokstav < 'a')
        {
            bokstav = (char)(bokstav + 26);
        }

        //Then save
        längd[i] = bokstav; ` so far tried this

Comment: you can see it above as well, in the "main" text

Comment: But you're only attempting to deal with lower case.

Comment: i know, tried different ways to solve uppercase but dont know how to do

Comment: if (bokstav > 'Z')
        {
            bokstav = (char)(bokstav - 26);
        }
        else if (bokstav < 'A')
        {
            bokstav = (char)(bokstav + 26);
        }
Replacing the lower case lettera with uppercase

Comment: If you replace lowercase with uppercase then it will only work for uppercase. I thought you wanted it to work for both.